# How does golang parse the illegal string of url in the nginx log

Tags: json, go, nginx

I am trying to use Golang to parse the **Nginx access log file** to json, but some special url will cause parsing failure

For example:

```golang
str := "{\"time\":\"2023-07-20T10:11:29+08:00\",\"method\":\"GET\",\"uri\":\"/www.baidu.com/eu\\xG8\\xB8\\xE9\\xQ1\\x9F\\xZ7\\xE8\\xAE\\xCF\\xF9\\xB5\\x12\"}"
data := make(Data)

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &data); err == nil {
    log.Printf("json success, %#v", data)
} else {
    log.Print(err)
}
// stderr: invalid character 'x' in string escape code
```

https://go.dev/play/p/ubhsABdHV2G

I searched and found that it seems to be caused by special characters, but how should this be solved?

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Your string is malformed, that’s all.

Comment: sorry, but I can't decide it, this is a content of **nginx access log**

Comment: As @Volker said you string is Malformed use net/url library for example Url Escape query or Url Path Escape https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#QueryEscape and will solve your issue.

Comment: The problem is the string literal in source code. That should be obvious from the error message.

Comment: @ Gatusko  The url string is not generated by the url library, but the string generated by nginx. I can't change it. I just want to parse it without reporting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Go stumbles upon strings like `\xG8` b/c `\x` means there's a hexcode following, but `G8` (among others) is no hexcode. No clue what `\xG8` is supposed to mean, but if you just want to read as a string where `\xG8` is not interpreted as a (faulty) hex value, you have to escape the `\` with another backslash, e.g. with something like

```golang
strAdjusted := strings.ReplaceAll(str, "\\x", "\\\\x")
```

It looks a bit weird because all these backslashes, but basically `\\` will be resolved to one `\` character without any special meaning, so you replace `\` with `\\` in `str`, telling Go not to interpret the `\x` in there as an escape for hexcode.

That said, I'm not sure whether this brings you closer to your aims. It's still a broken url. You'ld have to apply some custom logic to map `\xG8...` back to a valid character to get working url out of it.